# I have this problem : No Firebase app has been created : call firebase.initializeApp() and it is called in the main function

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

this is the main:

```
# import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'authentication/signing_option.dart';
import 'introScreen/intro_page.dart';

void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'SwipeAway',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
          primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
        ),
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: IntroScreenWithDelay(), // Use IntroScreenWithDelay to control navigation
    );
  }
}

class IntroScreenWithDelay extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _IntroScreenWithDelayState createState() => _IntroScreenWithDelayState();
}

class _IntroScreenWithDelayState extends State<IntroScreenWithDelay> {
  bool showIntro = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          showIntro = false;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: showIntro ? IntroScreen() : ChooseSigningOption(),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is another class that I want to cooperate with a Firestore database:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:swipe_away/authentication/user_model.dart';
class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignUpState createState() => _SignUpState();
}

class _SignUpState extends State<SignUp> {
  int _currentPageIndex = 0;
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentPageIndex = index;
    });
  }

  TextEditingController firstNameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController lastNameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController phoneController = TextEditingController();

  String firstNameFromDatabase = "";
  String lastNameFromDatabase = "";

  @override
  void dispose() {
    firstNameController.dispose();
    lastNameController.dispose();
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
    phoneController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  final _db=FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  createUser(UserModel user) async{
   await _db.collection("users").add(user.toJson()).whenComplete(
          () =>
          Get.snackbar("Success", "Your account has been created.",
              snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
              backgroundColor: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.1),
            colorText: Colors.green),
    )
        .catchError((error, stackTrace) {
      Get.snackbar("Error", "Something went wrong. Try again",
          snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
          backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent.withOpacity(0.1),
          colorText: Colors.red);
      print(error.toString());
    }
    );
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF171717),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF454545),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Image.asset('assets/icons/left_arrow2.png'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'SwipeAway',
          style: GoogleFonts.kronaOne(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.06,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Image.asset(
              'assets/icons/notifications_icon.png',
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              // Handle notifications icon tap
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/icons/user_icon.png',
                scale: 0.5,
                color: Colors.blueGrey.shade100,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            Center(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.08,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  'Sign Up',
                  style: GoogleFonts.kronaOne(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.06,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 35),
            Center(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: firstNameController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'First Name',
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Color(0x9ED9D9D9),
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        ),
                      ),
                      style: GoogleFonts.kronaOne(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.03,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: lastNameController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Last Name',
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Color(0x9ED9D9D9),
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        ),
                      ),
                      style: GoogleFonts.kronaOne(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.03,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Center(
              child: TextField(
                controller: emailController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Email',
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Color(0x9ED9D9D9),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  ),
                ),
                style: GoogleFonts.kronaOne(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.03,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Center(
              child: TextField(
                controller: passwordController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Password',
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Color(0x9ED9D9D9),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  ),
                ),
                style: GoogleFonts.kronaOne(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.03,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                ),
                obscureText: true,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Center(
              child: TextField(
                controller: phoneController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Phone No',
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Color(0x9ED9D9D9),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  ),
                ),
                style: GoogleFonts.kronaOne(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.03,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Center(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  if(formKey.currentState!.validate()){

                    final user=UserModel(
                        firstName: firstNameController.text.trim(),
                        lastName: lastNameController.text.trim(),
                        email: emailController.text.trim(),
                        telephoneNumber: phoneController.text.trim(),
                        password: passwordController.text.trim(),
                    );
                  }
                },
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Color(0xFFD56A1B),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 80, vertical: 8),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  'Submit',
                  style: GoogleFonts.kronaOne(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.06,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Image.asset(
              'assets/icons/home_icon.png',
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.08,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15,
            ),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Image.asset(
              'assets/icons/saved_icon.png',
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.08,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15,
            ),
            label: 'Saved',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Image.asset(
              'assets/icons/bookings_icon.png',
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.08,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15,
            ),
            label: 'Bookings',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Image.asset(
              'assets/icons/myAccount_icon.png',
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.08,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15,
            ),
            label: 'My Account',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _currentPageIndex,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and those are my build.gradle files:
android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this is the app/build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.helena.swipe_away2"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.helena.swipe_away2"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 33
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.2.0')
    // Add other Firebase dependencies here if needed
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
```

.......................................................................

and this is the userModel in case it matters:

````
  final String? id;
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final String email;
  final String telephoneNumber;
  final String password;

  const UserModel({
    this.id,
    required this.firstName,
    required this.lastName,
    required this.email,
    required this.telephoneNumber,
    required this.password,
    });

    toJson(){
      return {
        "FirstName" : firstName,
        "LastName" : lastName,
        "Email" : email,
        "PhoneNo:" : telephoneNumber,
        "Password" : password,
      };
    }
}```
...........................................................................................
I tried to modify the .gradle files and to follow YouTube videos and nothing, also firebase is configured on my laptop.I am logged in so I think this is not the problem.In my Firestore database I made a collection for users named "users" and I put the google-services.json in the correct path.I don't know what should I do.
I tried every advice on the internet and nothing is working for me, help..also I am new to flutter and firebase.
````

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide firebase option.

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

}
```

To generate options run `firebase init` on terminal.

More about [initialize-firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android#initialize-firebase)

Comment: You need to use firebase cli to generate this. try to follow the attached link, also you can check `flutterfire config`